# 'Shift' of a graded ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, graded-rings

I am trying to understand Definition 3.1 of the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf). We have a unital ring $R$ with a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading $(R_i)$ that is commutative i.e. $xy=(-1)^{|x||y|}yx$, and an $R$-module $I$ with a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading $(M_i)$ i.e. $R_iM_j\subseteq M_{i+j}$. $J$ is a *graded ideal* which (as far as I can tell) means that $J_i=J\cap R_i$ for all $i$. Let $d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**I am trying to understand the role of $\Sigma$ in $\Sigma^d J$.** I'm sure it means some kind of shift (changing degree by $d$) but am unsure how this is defined explicitly, and how it necessarily leads to a well-defined grading. How should I make sense of this?

Comment: Consider the ideal $J$ as a graded $R$-module rather than an ideal. Then $\Sigma^d J$ is the graded $R$-module consisting of $J$ shifted by $d$. ($\Sigma^d J$ is not an ideal anymore, in general.)