# Graded version of Baer's criterion for injectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, graded-rings

I am trying to make sense of Definition 3.1 of the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf). See my related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725864/shift-of-a-graded-ideal?noredirect=1#comment10014549_4725864) from earlier today. Here is the definition below:

> Let $R$ be a graded ring and $I$ be a graded $R$-module. We say that $I$ satisfies the *Baer condition* if for each graded ideal $J$ in $R$, each $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and each $R$-module homomorphism $\phi:\Sigma^d J\to I$, there exists $m\in I_d$ for which $\phi(a)=am$ for all $a\in J$.

(I assume $a\in I$ in the text is a typo).

I am a little puzzled by the role of $\phi$ in this. It is a map between two **graded** $R$-modules, and yet the authors do not insist that the morphism must respect the grading. Also $\Sigma^d J$ and $J$ are identical as $R$-modules, so the grading must come into this somewhere. What is going on here?

Comment: I don't think they are identical as graded modules, so it must be a graded homomorphism

Comment: The first paragraph in the paper says, "The graded setting is assumed everywhere," and also at the start of Section 2 they say, "let $\textrm{Mod}_R$ be the category of graded R-modules." So I would assume that $\phi$ must be a graded module homomorphism of degree 0.

Comment: Yes exactly what @JohnPalmieri said, when autors only use module without graded they mean concentrated in degree $0$ since your $I$ is

Comment: @JohnPalmieri By 'homomorphism of degree 0' do you mean that homogeneous elements of degree $i$ are mapped to homogeneous elements of degree $i$ (for each $i$)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Degree-preserving, in other words.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri So I'm guessing what is meant in the paper is that $\phi(J_{i+d})\subseteq I_i$ for all $i$...

Comment: It's either $\phi(J_{i+d}) \subseteq I_i$ or $\phi(J_{i-d}) \subseteq I_i$, depending on conventions. I think it's the latter in this paper, but it doesn't matter in this definition since it's "for all $i$".